# How to check file content in a python script being run in a perforce trigger?

Tags: python, perforce

**Goal:**
I am trying to run checks against files users want to submit to validate them and block submission of bad files

**Docs:**
I am referencing https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4sag/Content/P4SAG/scripting.triggers.submits.content.html which says

> The following change-content trigger is a Bourne shell script that ensures that every file in every changelist contains a copyright notice for the current year.

And goes

```
  # p4 print -q //depot/src/file.c@=12345
```

**My Code:**
My perforce trigger table entry looks something like

```
check_hydra_json_trigger change-submit //foo/... "C:\Python38\python.exe %//foo/script.py% %changelist%"
```

My `script.py` file looks like

```
changelist_number = sys.argv[1]
change = p4.run_describe(changelist_number)
file_list = change[0]['depotFile']

for file_path in file_list:
    if file_path.endswith('.json'):         
        output = p4.run("print", "-o", temp_file, f"{file_path}@{changelist_number}")
    
        data = None
        try:
            with open(temp_file, "r") as temp_file_contents:
                data = json.load(temp_file_contents)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error: Failed to load json {file_path}. Is file properly formatted?")
            print(f"Exception: {e}")
```

My issue is `temp_file` always contains the contents of the depot file, not the file that we're trying to submit.

No luck having `change-content` as my trigger instead...

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but note that you'll want to `exit(1)` if you want the trigger to fail the submit after it prints the error (e.g. in your `except` block).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
output = p4.run("print", "-o", temp_file, f"{file_path}@{changelist_number}")
```

to:

```
output = p4.run("print", "-o", temp_file, f"{file_path}@={changelist_number}")
```

and make sure that your trigger is running as `change-content` rather than `change-submit`.

The important detail is the `@=` revision specifier, which can be used to refer to unsubmitted files on the server (i.e. a midflight submit in a `change-content` trigger, or a shelved change -- note that at the time `change-submit` fires, the files are not yet on the server).

Normally a revision specifier can only ever refer to *submitted* revisions, but `@=` is a special exception when it refers to a pending change that contains either mid-submit or shelved files.